# Which gem do I need to use Rack::Session::Memcache?

Tags: ruby, memcached, rack

I want my rack app to use Rack::Session::Memcache as a session store for my rack app. Alas, the documentation http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Session/Memcache.html doesn't specify which gem it requires!!! :(

So what gems do I need installed? I installed the gem `memcache` but I still get an error

> `require': cannot load such file -- memcache (LoadError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/rack.gemspec suggests the gem **memcache-client**

> s.add_development_dependency 'memcache-client'

But it's probably better to use Rack::Session::Dalli (gem dalli) . Still Memcache [How to specify memcache server to Rack::Session::Memcache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786976/how-to-specify-memcache-server-to-racksessionmemcache/12787492#12787492)